# checking if a directory exists on a remote machine and copying the file on it

Tags: java, file, copy

I have a shared folder F on a remote machine M. Now I want to run a program on my local machine which does following.

```
Check if subfoder  S exists with \\remoteMachine\F
   if S exists then copy my file tstfile.txt within S
   else if S does not exist then 
      create S at \\remoteMachine\F and 
      copy tstfile.txt within S.
```

Currently I am using the following to copy file, but I can't figure out the folder copy logic

```
 InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\testData\\aks.txt"));
 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("\\remotemachine\\tst.txt"));

 //Transfer bytes from in to out
 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
 int len;
 while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
     out.write(buf, 0, len);
 }
 in.close();
 out.close();
 System.out.append("done with copying");
```

Comment: Check if subfoder  S existis with \\remoteMachine\F
   if S exists present then copy my file tstfile.txt within S
   else if S doesnot exists then create S at \\remoteMachine\F and then copy tstfile.txt          within S.How to do this?

Comment: How to do /what/? You've sketched a nice algorithm, now just translate it to java.

Comment: yes.I can do it on my local system.But i dont know how to do it remotely on a remote machine

Comment: What's the difference once you have a shared drive? The only problem seems to be to get those backslashes right. Please show us what you tried and what the result was.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("\\remotemachine\\tst.txt"));
```

Should instead be:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("\\\\remotemachine\\tst.txt"));
```

You need to escape those backslashes properly. The other (potentially easier?) option is to map the remote machine as a network drive and access it more conveniently such as:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("M:\tst.txt"));
```